# Is there a way of aligning depth image on color image after saving the images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, alignment, realsense

I have a dataset containing RGB images and their Depth images **before** alignment:

- RGB images - (480, 640, 3)
- Depth images - (480, 640)

The camera used is **RealSense depth d435i**.

Is there a way of aligning the Depths along the RGB images of this dataset?
I prefer python but if there is a simple way in a different language it's all the same for me.

FYI - I know how align the images during capturing using realsense package in python but the question above is on saved dataset, after capturing the images.

Thank You.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, I have not.